# Printing list items on separate lines

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to print a list of grades with each grade on its own line and this is what I have so far

```
grades = [100, 100, 90, 40, 80, 100, 85, 70, 90, 65, 90, 85, 50.5]

def print_grades(grades):  

    for grade in grades:  

       print grade
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
grades = [100, 100, 90, 40, 80, 100, 85, 70, 90, 65, 90, 85, 50.5]

for grade in grades:  

    print grade
```

it should do what you want. My only concern with the original snippet is that you're not actually calling the function you defined. Instead, try this

```
grades = [100, 100, 90, 40, 80, 100, 85, 70, 90, 65, 90, 85, 50.5]

def print_grades(grades):
    for grade in grades:
        print grade

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_grades(grades)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
grades = [100, 100, 90, 40, 80, 100, 85, 70, 90, 65, 90, 85, 50.5]

def print_grades(grades):  
    for grade in grades:  
       print grade
#main code here 
print_grades(grades)
```